# Atomic property with custom getter

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, atomic, lazy-initialization

I have a class with a property declared as:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *links;
```

I want to lazily instantiate it so have the following custom getter:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)links {

    if (!_links) {
        _links = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    return _links;
}
```

My app has progressed somewhat and the object can now be accessed from different threads.  I change the declaration to:

```
@property (atomic, strong) NSMutableArray *links;
```

> This generates a compiler warning: Writeable atomic property cannot
>   combine a synthesised setter with a user defined getter.

Which I understand - I think.  **My question is, it is *correct* to do the following, in order to create an atomic property with a custom getter?**:

- Create my own instance variable _links
- Wrap my getter in `@synchronized`
- Create a user defined setter, also wrapped in `@synchronized`

**EDIT**: this is the code for my new custom setter and getter:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)links {

   if (!_links) {
       @synchronized(self) {
           if (!_links) {
               _links = [NSMutableArray array];
           }
       }
   }

   return _links;    
}

- (void)links:(NSMutableArray *)links {
       @synchronized(self) {
         _links = links;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

First, just because the property may be accessed from multiple threads doesn't mean that a) it needs to be atomic, nor that b) making it atomic is sufficient to make it thread-safe.

In particular, the property type is `NSMutableArray*`, which means that any caller gets the mutable array and can mutate it without restriction, which is inherently thread-unsafe. You should basically *never* make a property with mutable type. All changes to the property should have to go through accessor methods so you can control or, at a minimum, react to changes.

Second, your getter is using the [double-checked lock anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking). It is not safe in C-based languages like Objective-C. Don't do that.

That said, you're correct that if you make a property atomic and you implement either the getter or the setter, then you must implement both and you are also responsible for implementing the synchronization to enforce the atomicity. Using `@synchronized()` is suitable, so long as you don't use the double-checked locking approach.

But you really need to make your **class** thread-safe with respect to that property (and any others that can be accessed from multiple threads), which requires more than making the property atomic.

Comment: Thanks for the great advice Ken.  I am new to multi-threaded app development.  I have read the article at the link and I still can see why the double-check pattern is not thread safe.  My plan based on what you are staying is to hide the property and make accessor methods.  That said I would still want to lazy instantiate the array, can you give any guidance on how to do that in a thread safe say?

Comment: Languages such as C have a fairly weak memory model and compilers, CPUs, and caches can actually do very surprising things to memory accesses. Reads and writes to memory do not necessarily occur in the order that they appear in the code. So, for example, thread A could be inside the `@synchronized` block in the getter. It can actually write and make visible to other threads a pointer in `_links` *before* the pointed-to memory's contents has been written and made available to other threads. So, thread B can come along and find that `_links` is non-`nil`, but when it tries to use it, it crashes.

Comment: As to making a class thread-safe, there's no simple recipe for the general case. You would have to explain what the class represents and what it does. What is the interface (beyond just the `links` property) and how is it expected to be used?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you want a setter. And I wonder why you want the property to be atomic.

The easiest and correct way, if you want a getter and a setter, is to write

```
- (NSMutableArray *)links{
    @synchronized (self)
    {
        if(!_links){
            _links = [NSMutableArray.alloc init];
        }
    }
    return _links;
}

- (void)setLinks:(NSMutableArray *)links{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        _links = links;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got the check in the getter backwards. You only want to instantiate a new array if `_links` **is** `nil`.

Comment: The reason for the setter is, it appears I can't have an atomic property without both a getter and setter.  The reason for the setter is to lazy instantiate it.